# "Maaneh Loshn" - מענה לשון

Tags: tefilla, chabad, cemetery-grave, yiddish, tzaddikim

Maaneh Loshn is a [profoundly](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/91379/jewish/Maaneh-Lashon.htm) beautiful tefila once said by [many people](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/91380/jewish/Publishers-Foreword.htm), now mostly said by Lubavitcher Chasidim at their [Ohel](http://www.ohelchabad.org/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/3402126).

1) Does anyone else say Maaneh Loshn today besides Chabad?

2) The second site linked suggests that Yiddish translations of this tefila were once extremely popular. Is it possible to find a Yiddish translation of the Chabad nusach of Maaneh-Loshn?

Comment: Not the Chabad nusach (as far as I know), but here's a Yiddish translation of Maaneh Lashon: https://www.yiddishbookcenter.org/collections/yiddish-books/spb-nybc210910/maaneh-lashon-im-ivri-taytsh-hu-seder-tehinot-al-bet-almin

Comment: @ezra Thanks. I am sure a translation of the Chabad nusach once existed; maybe I shall ask the library

Comment: I'm almost certain it did. Contact [Kehot](http://store.kehotonline.com/). They have a lot of things they don't sell on their website but have by request.

Comment: @SAH according to the forward you linked, maaneh lashon is a nickname for a collections of psalms said at a grave. if so the answer is yes, almost every community has a formula to say at a grave

Comment: @heshy It's brachos, tehillim, and some extremely moving prayers with lines gathered from tehillim and elsewhere in Nach. I'm interested in a Yiddish translation of this particular set of prayers.